# Footer not sticking to the bottom of page for one page only

Tags: css, media-queries

I don't know if negative values are allowed.  I have tried os many different ways in fixing my footer to sit at the bottom of the page on mobile devices and nothing has worked.  finally I found a solution for negative bottom value, is this is acceptable in css/developer community?

```
@media screen and (min-width: 240px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .page-id-94 .site-footer .boldgrid.widget-widget {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 1%;
  }
}
```

I don't know if `.boldgrid.widget-widget` is doing anything so I may remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to modify the styles of a footer on a specific page then `.page-id-94 .site-footer` should do fine, `.boldgrid.widget-widget` is likely not targeting anything.  As for negative position values, they are fine and perfectly acceptable.

Comment: This isn't working, unfortunately.  Viewing my website on various devices is still not working because the footer is in the middle of the page for some.  hmmmm